# VB.NET Automatically include DLLs in specific folder

Tags: vb.net

I have a project where I have a directory called `plugins/` which will contain multiple DLLs.

As an example, I will have two (2) DLLs in my `plugins/` directory: `Visual.dll` and `Momen.dll`

Each of those will be a Class, `Visual.dll` will have the Class name `Visual` and `Momen.dll` will have the Class name `Momen`.

I need to make a loop that will loop through all DLL files in my `plugins/` directory; once in that loop, it will obviously know the file is `Visual.dll` or `Momen.dll`. First, it will need to include the DLLs (just as if I added them as References to my Project) so that I can use them. If the loop is at `Visual.dll`, I will then need it to create an instance of the `Visual` Class, and then execute a method called `Run()`

I'm a PHP developer, and relatively new to VB.NET, in PHP I'd be able to do something like, which would create a new instance of my `Visual` Class (while passing a few arguments), then execute the Run() method:

```
$className = "Visual";
$instance = new $className("arg1", "arg2");
$instance->Run();
```

I appreciate any help.
Thank you

Comment: .NET DLLs do not "run".  your app calls functions in them and/or creates an object from the class(es) in them.  e.g.: `myVisObj.DoSomething(foo)`  you might be looking for: `Friend myVis As VisualClassName = New VisualClassName`.  but I am not sure how plugins and folders play into the question

Comment: Hi Plutonix, I'm aware of this. The issue is I don't have the hardcoded name of "VisualClassName" at the time of execution. I have the name of the DLL, Visual.dll; from that, I can extract "Visual" which will be the Class name. I need to first include the DLL, then I need to create an instance of it. Once in the loop I will be able to know that the Class name is Visual, which I will set to a variable. From there, how do I create an instance of a Class, where the Class name will be stored in a variable?

Comment: MS has a small tutorial on this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b6174b62

Comment: Thank you very much, the_lotus. This will prove very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DLLs are .NET assemblies, then you can load them with [Assembly.LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That will give you a reference to an Assembly object.

You can use the assembly's `GetExportedTypes` method to view public types in the assembly, or the `GetType` overload that takes a string parameter to get a type from the assembly based on its name.

From there, you should be able to use an appropriate overload of [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create an instance of the class. From there, you should also be able to find and run its `Run` method through reflection.

*Edit* This is untested, but something like this might work (or be close to working):

```
    Dim plugin As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("test.dll")
    Dim pluginType As Type = plugin.GetType("Test")

    Dim instance As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType)
    Dim runMethod As MethodInfo = pluginType.GetMethod("Run")
    Dim param1 As String = "Hello"
    Dim param2 As String = "World"
    runMethod.Invoke(instance, New Object() {param1, param2})
```

If you're going to do much with plugins other than just load and run a method, then it might be worthwhile to look for a plugin framework to use.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I've been looking for. In terms of the Plugins, I believe I'll only need to execute the Run() method so I don't think it will be necessary to use a plugin framework. Thanks so much, pmcoltrane

Comment: Thank you again for your revision, I can't wait to try this out!

Comment: pmcoltrane, I've just implemented this method and it works flawlessly. Thanks again